Unable to access GitHub profile publicly, but can log in with credentials. 404 Not Found
I'm experiencing an issue with my GitHub account. I can log in to my account with my credentials, but when others try to visit my profile, they get a "404 Not Found" error. However, my profile is set to public, and I haven't made any changes to the visibility settings recently.
I can still access my profile while logged in.
The profile URL is correct.
The account is not deleted or disabled.
I've checked and confirmed that my profile visibility is set to public.
What could be causing this issue? Why can I access my account but others cannot view my profile?
Has anyone encountered this problem before, or does anyone have suggestions on how to fix it?
https://github.com/ibrahimdeniz24
I made profile visibility changes but there was no solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have to contact GitHub support. See, for example, here.
